# What is an "annotation" in Apache Thrift, and what is it used for?

Tags: thrift

The Thrift parser has a definition for an "annotation":

https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=thrift.git;a=blob;f=compiler/cpp/src/thrifty.yy;h=da5c562f9d7adf87b21e4c3ae30fbb9657e0c8b3;hb=HEAD#l85

What are these meant to be used for, and can the information that they contain be accessed in the generated client and/or server code?

Comment: May I ask why you are asking? Is there a specific problem that you plan to solve usin g annotations, or just curiosity?

Comment: If was wondering if, for instance, its possible to attach arbitrary attributes to structures that client code could inspect at runtime... for example, `( validation.regex = "/.*@.*\.com/" )` or something like that.

Comment: Not that I am aware of, but Java is not my area of expertise. You may want to throw that question into the mailing list. Worth a try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Annotations are used to associate metadata with types defined in the Thrift definition (".thrift") file. [The `AnnotationThrift.test` file](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=thrift.git;a=blob;f=test/AnnotationTest.thrift;h=06bf57194fc06a6b9eae7138e196bdefca260618;hb=HEAD) in the source distribution has examples.

Here, for instance, is a `struct` with annotations (in parentheses):

```
struct foo {
  1: i32 bar ( presence = "required" );
  2: i32 baz ( presence = "manual", cpp.use_pointer = "", );
  3: i32 qux;
  4: i32 bop;
} (
  cpp.type = "DenseFoo",
  python.type = "DenseFoo",
  java.final = "",
  annotation.without.value,
)
```

Looking at the code, it seems annotations are only ever used to provide directives to the compiler—for instance the C++ compiler uses the `cpp.type` annotation, if it's present, to [override a type's name](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=thrift.git;a=blob;f=compiler/cpp/src/generate/t_cpp_generator.cc;h=3a190f5b16a29b336df00c53e34b44dd6f3c66ec;hb=HEAD#l4499) in the generated code.

I see nothing that suggests the annotations themselves are ever reproduced in or accessible to the generated code, though if such code *does* exist it'd be located in [`compiler/cpp/src/generate/`](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=thrift.git;a=tree;f=compiler/cpp/src/generate;hb=HEAD).

Answer (score 2):

As Simon pointed out, annotations can be imagined as extension points to the basic IDL language to control certain aspects of the code generation. They are quite often language specific, but not limited to that. In some cases annotations have become part of the core IDl later. Another thing is, that annotations are still quite poorly documented (I'm being kind here).

> can the information that they contain be accessed in the generated client and/or server code?

It depends on the annotation and on what you mean by "accessed". If you change the base class by means of an annotation, or if you make a Java class `final`, the information is of course present in the generated code.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear by what I meant be 'accessed'... for instance Java also has annotations, they optionally can be read via reflection at runtime; I was wondering if any of the generators encode the annotation information into the generated structures, but the answers seem to suggest that they don't.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We have leveraged annotations via a [Go Thrift parser](https://github.com/samuel/go-thrift). Examples include a Thrift linter where annotations selectively disable checks.