# Thrift message at the end of exception

Tags: thrift

I run into the following thrift file but couldn't understand what the last line is doing?

```
exception CommunicationException {
1: i32 source;
2: list<string> messages;
3: string message;
} (message="message")   // what does this (message...) do?
```

Answer (score 0):

That's called an [annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25631235/what-is-an-annotation-in-apache-thrift-and-what-is-it-used-for).

Funny enough, this particular one seems not to be used at all. So it might be some leftover from earlier days maybe. Or the producer of the IDL file uses a non-standard patched compiler version inhouse that actually uses it.